# ios: how do I check for app vs extension context

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions

Do I need a global bool to decide if the code is executing
in the app or extension context or there is some predefined #if I could use?

Need to decide if I could use UserDefaults.standard
or fallback to shared userdefaults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your extension target's `bundleIdentifier` will be different than your main app you can check `bundleIdentifier` value. Which can be accessed by:

```
Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
```

I've tested this on a Today Extension only and not sure if it'd work for other extensions. For me the output was like this:

Main App: `com.example.app`

Extension: `com.example.app.today`

Finally this method would allow you to differentiate the extensions in which the code is running.

```
static var isInExtension: Bool
{
    //        print ("main bundleIdentifier \(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier)")
    if Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier?.hasSuffix("Extention") ?? false {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add -DNSExtension in other C flags and Other C++ flags in build settings of the extension target.
Now you can check for the extension like as below

```
#ifdef NSExtension

#endif
```

Comment: this would've worked 5-10 years ago, but, sadly, not with the trash swift preprocessor. Not in 10 minutes I was willing to put into making it work anyway.